# Codeigniter ERROR LOADING PAGE

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery-mobile, authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRGsM.png)

Im tryng to develop a login system in Codeigniter but for some reason, when the form is submited and ERROR LOADING PAGE is displayed. I tried to reach out many possibilities on the action="" in the form but it always gives me the same error. Can someone help me with that?

There follows my code:

My View signIn.php

```
<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>

<body>
  <div id="login" data-role="page" class="outpage">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>login</h1></div>
    <div class="confpage" style="text-align:center;">
      <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>template/images/logomarca.jpg" />
        <form action="user/login" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password">
        <button class="buttonDefault" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
      <a data-transition="slide" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Back</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

My controller user.php

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

    }

    public function signIn(){

        $this->load->view('signIn');

    }


    public function login(){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|callback_check_database');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

            $this->load->view('signUp');

        }else{

            $this->load->view('admin/admin');

        }



    }


    function check_database($password){

        //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
        $email = $this->input->post('email');


        //query the database
        $result = $this->user->login($email, $password);

        if($result) {

            $sess_array = array();

            foreach($result as $row){
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $row->id;
                    $_SESSION['fname'] = $row->fname;
                    $sess_array = array(
                                        'id' => $row->id,
                                        'fname' => $row->fname);

                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);

            }
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid email or password');
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

And thats my model user_model.php

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_model extends CI_Model{


public function __contruct(){

    parent::__contruct();


}


    public function signUp($data){

        $this->db->insert('users', $data);

    }


    public function login($email, $password) {

        $password = md5($password);

        $this -> db -> select('id, fname, lname, password');
        $this -> db -> from('users');
        $this -> db -> where('email', $email);
        $this -> db -> where('password', $password);
        $this -> db -> limit(1);

        $query = $this -> db -> get();

        if($query -> num_rows() == 1) {

            return $query->result();

        }else {

            return false;

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: `<form action="/user/login" method="post">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL used in the form action itself is incorrect. Obviously, you will get an error. Try using the following URL.

```
<?php echo site_url(); ?>user/login
```

Hope this can help you.

[image]

Comment: Still doesnt work. There must be a chance there is something wrong on Jquery Mobile?

Comment: Have you added base_url in the config file??

Comment: It has nothing to do with jquery. Please inspect the webpage by pressing F12 and send the screenshot. This can help me to find what is the exact problem.

Comment: Edit and add it to your question.

Comment: I included. Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Actually, you are missing a backslash near `index.php` and have added a double backslash in jquery src. Please refer the image.

Comment: Please go to `config` file and change the `base_url` as `http://localhost:8888/Housing_around/` Maybe you are missing the backslash after Housing_around. Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much